# How to hide a link if it was visited?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to remove a link from a page when it was visited. But...how, if the pseudo-class :visited have privacy restrictions? (i can not use display: none, for example)

(How i would like to do) Example:

`.someclass a:link {display:block;}`

`.someclass a:visited {display:none;}`

Thanks guys.

Detail: i'll use a external link too, so i can not use jquery cookies or localstore, and the links will be delivered by email, therefore i can not use jquery on click in the class "X".

Comment: Does this fiddle capture your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/NGSs8/

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I try this and for Chrome I figured out that `:visited` is used only for links which user visit from the site. Then, you're not able to check if user has ever been on referenced site before. 

You should try catch `click` event, store the cookie with link URL and when user go back to your site you will store site url in coolies into database and do not render visited link for user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this a:visited css style work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331688/why-doesnt-this-avisited-css-style-work)

Comment: If you're delivering these links by email, you won't be able to change an already delivered email.  Are you hoping that the CSS will be able to hide it inside of the email?

Comment: Hello Boris, i'll use a external link and this doesn't work correctly, because i'll send the links via email too.

Comment: Sorry showdev, i found much askes, but nothing worked and i'm sending my case to search some solution to this.

Comment: No ntg, the page will be changed, not the email. I want only show a link when the user visited the link, is a perpetual launch and the links of the videos will be sent to the leads email.

Comment: Related [CSS :link and :visited pseudo-classes - are web browsers adhering to the spec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792010/css-link-and-visited-pseudo-classes-are-web-browsers-adhering-to-the-spec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only attribute you can change via the :visited pseudo-class is the color. This is in response to a security issue where javascript could be used to measure the computed style of a link and determine if the user had visited that url. This has been patched in the recent years, so you should avoid relying on it for functionality like you are desiring. See the article here for a more detailed description:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/styling-visited-links/

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is to color the visited link same color as background e.g.

```
a:link {display:block;}
a:visited {color:white}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NGSs8/5/